# Is it possible to extend List<T> but only for T = exact type?

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I'm experimenting with extending classes and managed to extend `List<T>` for fun like so:

```
public static void SomeCustomSort<T>(this List<T> list, string item)
{
    if (typeof(T) != typeof(string) || list.Count == 0)
        return;

    // doStuff();
}
```

I wondered if there was a smarter way to extend `List<T>` only for `List<string>` so that my extension method is not listed or accessable for any other type `T`

Comment: if this is a sorting method, consider implementing a comparer instead.

Comment: That works for custom types but what about generic ones? Can I re-implement the IComparer for string?

Comment: you can implement your own `IComparer<string>`

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/234b841s(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just make your method non-generic:

```
 public static void SomeCustomSort(this List<string> list, string item)
```

and specify exact type it should work with

---

NOTE: With void methods even if you want to restrict extension method parameter to some set of types (e.g. all implementors of some interface or some non-sealed class with classes derived from it) I would not recommend using generic method with parameter constraint:

```
public static void SomeCustomSort<T>(this List<T> animals)
   where T: IAnimal
```

Why? Because it overcomplicates your code. Non-generic method is more simple to understand than generic method. Generic method without constraint is more simple to understand than generic method with constraint. You should start from the simplest solution which is easy to understand. What sounds more natural to you?

- "It sorts list of animals"
- "It sorts list of items of any type"
- "It sorts list of items of any type which is animal"

When to use generic type constraint? When you return items from your method and you don't want to lose information about the exact type of list items. Consider method which returns animals by some weight filter

```
public static IEnumerable<IAnimal> WhereWeightBelow(this List<IAnimal> animals, int weight)
```

If you'll pass list of dogs to this method, you will lose intellisense for all dog-specific information in the method output.

```
dogs.WhereWeightBelow(10).Where(d => d. /* oops only IAnimal members here */)
```

Returning generic type will preserve all dog info for you.

Answer (score 5):

Another alternative not yet mentioned:

```
public static void SomeCustomSort<T>(this List<T> list, string item) 
  where T: YourSpecificType
```

This allows you to specify more than just one type, for example:

```
public static void SomeCustomSort<T>(this List<T> list, string item) 
  where T: ISortable, ICustomInterface
```

Comment: This is what I tried initially but couldn't quite get it working. Is there any benefit as to why this should be done over the other way or just flavour?

Comment: Generic method restricted by single non-inheritable type? Upvoters, please provide pros of having such method as generic

Comment: @Ilhan  Using where T: you are allowed to specify different types, not just one, see my edit

Comment: Also I don't think I can specify 'string' as YourSpecificType am I wrong?

Comment: @Ilhan true, type should be non-sealed to be a generic constraint

Answer (score 4):

Just specify `T` instead of making it a generic method.

```
public static void SomeCustomSort(this List<string> list, string item)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just define exactly string type on your extension method

```
public static void SomeCustomSort(this List<string> list, string item)
{   

    // doStuff();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a constraint like this (in this example T would have to be of type Project):

```
public static void SomeCustomSort<T>(this List<T> list, string item)
        where T : Project    
    {    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would show you in the following example how you can easily expand a generic list.
I expanded the list to return random data from the list itself.

We have a class for example:

```
public class ExampleClass
{
     public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

We have now made a list of these classes in some method:

```
var exampleList = new List<ExampleClass>()
{
    new ExampleClass()
    {
         Name = "Class1"
    },
    new ExampleClass()
    {
         Name = "Class2"
    },
    new ExampleClass()
    {
         Name = "Class3"
    }
};

var randomList = exampleList.Random(2);
```

**The following is a simple implementation of returning random objects from a list**

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static IList<T> Random<T>(this IList<T> list, int numberOfResult) where T : class
    {
        if (list == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(list));
        if (numberOfResult <= 0 || numberOfResult > list.Count) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(numberOfResult));

        var random = new Random();
        var randomList = new List<T>();
        var randomNumbers = new List<int>();

        while (randomList.Count < numberOfResult)
        {
            var index = random.Next(list.Count);

            if (randomNumbers.IndexOf(index) < 0)
            {
                randomNumbers.Add(index);
                randomList.Add(list[index]);
            }
        }

        return randomList;
    }
}
```